# ui:include src attribute's EL is resolved to null in composite component

Tags: jsf-2, facelets, composite-component

I have composite component as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
      xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite" 
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
    <cc:interface>
        <cc:attribute name="path" shortDescription="Page Title" type="String"/>
    </cc:interface>
    <cc:implementation>
            <ui:include src="#{cc.attrs.path}"/>
    </cc:implementation>
</html>
```

Problem with above code is `#{cc.attrs.path}` is resolved to null. If `src` is hardcoded then `ui:include` works fine.

Tried checking `#{cc.attrs.path}` with `h:outputText` and path is displayed correctly, that means only in case of `ui:include` EL is not resolved. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

This code works just fine on my computer. The EL is resolved in any case, but I think the include failed because the file you try to include is malformed, or does not exist.

Maybe you could tell us what kind of file you try to include, and then give us a portion of this file ?

Comment: It is a regular xhtml file with bunch of standard and custom jsf components. The fact that hardcoded path works and file is loaded correctly, so I dont think it is an issue with file. I debugged code down to facelet/jsf source and noticed that EL was resolved to null. This composite component is created programmatically.

Comment: You're right. Could you show us how you set your composite in your page ? Another question: are you working with nested composites (composite into composite) ?